# How to turn off MacBook's internal display with external one connected?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, cinema-display

I have external monitor in work and I want to mirror MacBook's screen on it while I have the internal display turned off. But I found this as impossible task.  I know I could close the display and attach a keyboard but I want to use MacBook's keyboard (and let the computer breathe through it).

Comment: You can just turn the brightness all the way down

Comment: I know but this is not solution. I have MacBook Air and turning brightness down is not good for books performance. It's little bit more heating and sometimes has slower reaction.